# Count subscribers of RSS feed

Tags: php, rss, feed, feedburner, subscribe

After Google decided to shut down the API of feedburner, I've unsuccessfully searched the web for another way of displaying the current subscribers of an RSS feed.

Is there any way of doing this in PHP without the old feedburner API?

Comment: Is this for your own RSS feed, or for one that you don't own/control?

Comment: It is my own feed which I control 100%